# Is it possible to have multiple plugin modules in one intellij idea project?

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea

Is it possible to have multiple plugin modules in one intellij idea project??  I am creating one project in which i have multiple plugin modules but i am able to deploy only one plugin...For other plugins it throws following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: class with name 'com.im.rest.crud.GenerateCRUDRest' must be an instance of 'com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction'; got com.im.rest.crud.GenerateCRUDRest@15bfb121
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:288)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:232)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.getAction(ActionManagerImpl.java:225)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup.unStub(DefaultActionGroup.java:301)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup.getChildren(DefaultActionGroup.java:259)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionGroupUtil.isGroupEmpty(ActionGroupUtil.java:45)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionGroupUtil.isGroupEmpty(ActionGroupUtil.java:39)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.generation.actions.GenerateAction.update(GenerateAction.java:62)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction.beforeActionPerformedUpdate(AnAction.java:241)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareUpdate(ActionUtil.java:108)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:589)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.d(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:463)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:206)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:493)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Additionally it is also showing this error :
    Null child action in group Generate () of class class com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup, id=GenerateCRUDRest 
java.lang.Throwable

Comment: Do you mean that you are developing a number of plugins and you want to edit them all at once, as if they were modules of a single project?

Comment: yes, i am developing multiple plugin modules in a single project

Comment: ..but able to deploy a single module...i want to deploy all the modules...may be one at a time or all at once...any possible way?? please help

Comment: I do not see it as possible, but you would get a better answer on the forum. http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea